# jQuery load() show css preloader inside div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used a button to load contents from another source, inside a div using this code >

```
$('button').click({ 
  $('somediv').load('source.php');
});
```

Now I want to show a preloader div, containing css loader ; which should show when i press the button until all the contents from the source.php loaded inside the div. Can anyone please help me???

Comment: I have no problem with .load() function... it gets the contents easily, I just want to show a preloader gif or css div which will show until the contents fully loaded..

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback of `load()`:

```
$('button').click({ 
    // show a loading div or something before start
    $(".loading").show();

    $('somediv').load('source.php', function() {
        // this will be executed once 'script.php' was loaded
        // hide the loading
        $(".loading").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Great. You're welcome! Feel free to vote it up then. ;)